# ADL and typedefs

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, argument-dependent-lookup

In short, I am trying to understand the behavior of Argument-Dependent Lookup in C++. Some statements in ISO/IEC 14882:2017 (E) regarding ADL are not clear to me. I hope somebody would clarify them to me.

According to standard,

> Typedef names and using-declarations used to specify the types do not contribute to this set.

and

> When considering an associated namespace, the lookup is the same as the lookup performed when the
>   associated namespace is used as a qualifier (6.4.3.2) except that:
>
> - Any using-directive s in the associated namespace are ignored...

For me, these statements imply that ADL should completely ignore any `typedef`, or `using` occurrence. Probably, this is not the case. Consider the following example:

```
#include <iostream>                                                             

using namespace std;                                                            

namespace N2                                                                 
{
    struct B {};

    template <typename T>                                                       
    void func (const T&) {cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << endl;}  
};

namespace N                                                                     
{
    typedef N2::B C;             
}                                                                               

void tfunc (N::C) {}                                                     

int main ()                                                     
{                                                                                                                      
    func(tfunc);                                                                 
}
```

It works, i.e., the compiler is able to find `func`. So, what those quotes from the standard actually mean?

Answer (score 1):

This answer is provided by @IgorTandetnik.

What the standard is saying is that `N2` is among the associated namespaces of `tfunc`, but `N` is not. In other words, void `tfunc (N::C)` works exactly the same as `void tfunc(N2::B)`. If, in your example, you move func to `N`, it won't be found, despite the fact that, on the surface, the declaration of `tfunc` mentions `N`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if you just read a bit further down the standard, you can see why your code works. Specifically, N3337 [basic.lookup.argdep]/2 as shown below [emphasis mine]:

> The sets of namespaces and classes are determined in the following way:
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> — **If T is a function type**, its associated namespaces and classes are those associated with the **function
> parameter types** and those associated with the **return type**.

As you can see, if the argument passed is a function type (`tfunc`  in your case), types associated with all the parameters (`N2::B` is the only type), as well as the return type (`void` - fundamental type, so not counted) are considered to create a set of associated namespaces.